# "Your working in London next summer might be a great experience"

Tags: modal-verbs

I know I can use these modal verbs when talking to a specific person, but I am wondering if I can use all these three modal verbs with a *generic* subject "you" or "people".

1. Working in London next summer **could** be a great experience.
2. Working in London next summer **might** be a great experience.
3. Working in London next summer **will** be a great experience.

Do they all work with a *generic* subject "you" or "people". For example:

a) Your working in London...

b) People's working in London...

Comment: I don't get what you mean by generic subject.  This would be naturally be directed at a person, and refer to the that person.  It's not generic, it's specific.

Comment: For some reason known to the speaker, they believe that *for **anyone/people** to work in London next summer will/might/could be a great experience*, referring to people in general. In another context, the speaker believes that *for **him** to work in London next summer will/might/could be a great experience*, referring to his friend. Are these two sentences correct?

Comment: _People's working_ doesn't feel right to me, though I can't exactly say why. I'd prefer _For [people] to work in London..._ or _Working in London next summer could be a great experience for [people]._

Comment: @KateBunting, Thank you!